# Dymola licenses needed to generate DLL (NI Veristand) from Simulink

Tags: matlab, dll, simulink, dymola, fmi

I am working on generating code (DLL), which would work in [National Instruments, VeriStand](http://www.ni.com/veristand/). Initially, the model is created in Dymola, then the model is exported as an FMU into MATLAB/Simulink. Finally, the code is generated by selecting the NIVeristand.tlc.

The licenses so far that I have during compilation of the dymola model are:

Standard Ok

Simulink Ok

What more licenses do I need in order to generate DLL that would be used in NI VeriStand for Hardware-in-the Loop (HiL) simulation?

Thank you in advance for your time and interest.